Is the category of locally compact Abelian groups regular?
Is the category $ \mathsf{LCAb} $ of locally compact Abelian groups regular?
I want to form the category of relations internal to $ \mathsf{LCAb} $, but I suspect there may be technical difficulties.
The closest I could find was a reference stating that  $ \mathsf{LCAb} $ is quasi-Abelian [1], but I am not sure if that implies regularity, or something close enough to form a category of internal relations.
Partial answers or tips would be very much appreciated.
[1] Hoffmann, Norbert; Spitzweck, Markus, Homological algebra with locally compact Abelian groups, Adv. Math. 212, No. 2, 504-524 (2007). ZBL1123.22002.

I believe that locally compact Abelian groups do form a regular category but that you will need closed relations.  However, my reasons for this belief are outside the likely context of the question and unfortunately I don't have headspace to give the proof at the moment.

I used to think that this category has cokernels, hence coequalisers and finite limits, hence is regular. Where am I wrong?

It seems that a pre-abelian category $\mathscr A$ is quasi-abelian if and only if $\mathscr A$ and $\mathscr A^{\text{op}}$ are regular, more or less by definition. Indeed, quasi-abelian categories are assumed pre-abelian, so all finite limits and finite colimits exist, which takes care of parts 1 and 2 of the definition from nlab (or wikipedia). The third condition is equivalent to 'pullbacks of cokernels are cokernels', which (with its dual) is exactly the axiom of a quasi-abelian category.

What you need to check is that strict monomorphisms (resp. epimorphisms) are exactly the regular monomorphisms (resp. epimorphisms), which is the first remark in Schneiders, Quasi-abelian categories and sheaves, plus the usual trick that the (co)equaliser of $f$ and $g$ in an additive category agrees with the (co)kernel of $f-g$.

@Nandor not every category with coequalizers and finite limits is regular. Pullbacks of regular epimorphisms also have to stay regular, which isn't true for instance for the category of posets.

@Kevin Carlson Thanks!

Sorry I was thinking of compact (Hausdorff) Abelian groups and my argument there probably doesn't extend to locally compact ones, but here is the idea anyway:  Compact Hausdorff spaces form a pretopos, ie a category with finite limits, finite coproducts and coequalisers that behave as well as those in Set. Then closed equivalence relations have coequalisers that are proper maps and stable under pullback.  For a finitary single sorted algebraic theory, the coequalisers of congruences are homomorphisms.

Let me post my comment as an answer.
Lemma. Let $\mathscr A$ be an additive category. Then $\mathscr A$ is quasi-abelian if and only if $\mathscr A$ is pre-abelian (has finite limits and colimits) and both $\mathscr A$ and $\mathscr A^{\operatorname{op}}$ are regular.
In particular, $\operatorname{LCA}$ is regular since it is quasi-abelian.
Proof of Lemma. By definition, a quasi-abelian category is a pre-abelian category $\mathscr A$ such that

Kernels are preserved by pushout.
Cokernels are preserved by pullback.

On the other hand, a category $\mathscr A$ with finite limits and colimits is regular if and only if

Regular epimorphisms are preserved by pullback.

(The other two axioms follow from existence of finite limits and colimits.)
When $\mathscr A$ is additive, then $X \to Y$ is a regular epimorphism if and only if it is the coequaliser of some pair $f,g \colon Z \rightrightarrows X$ if and only if it is the cokernel of some arrow $h \colon Z \to X$ (namely take $h = f-g$, and conversely $f=h$ and $g=0$). So condition 3 is just condition 2. Likewise, the dual of condition 3 is condition 1. $\square$
